# curl -u to javascript fetch()

Tags: javascript, curl, fetch, splunk

I have this curl command

```
curl -k -u username:password https://HOST:8089/services/search/jobs
```

I want get the data via Javascript.

Is fetch() the right method?

How to i convert the curl command into the fetch method?

Comment: Have you read any documentation on `fetch`? Is there a particular part that is causing you problems? Providing an [mcve] of your efforts so far would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Postman](https://www.postman.com/), you can import a curl command and then view code snippets for different languages:

- To import. Import -> Raw Text (past the curl command)
- To get the code snippet -> Below the save button in the request tab, click on **Code**. Choose what you need.

Not a direct answer to your question but hope it can help you now and in the future